# Loop through a repeated node list, check if an element does not exist and return an empty value to Excel

Tags: xml, excel, vba, xpath

```
<rootElement>
<n0:Partner>
            <n1:Identifier>EMH38</n1:Identifier>
            <n1:A>
                <n1:B>
                    <n1:C>WZFR8</n1:C>
                    <n1:D>Coll</n1:D>
                    <n1:E>1</n1:E>
                </n1:B>
                <n1:B>
                    <n1:C>X3HV7</n1:C>
                    <n1:D>Coll</n1:D>
                    <n1:E>2</n1:E>
                </n1:B>
                <n1:B>
                    <n1:C>X5E86</n1:C>
                    <n1:D>Coll</n1:D>
                    <n1:E>3</n1:E>
                </n1:B>
                <n1:B>
                    <n1:C>X5FC6</n1:C>
                    <n1:D>Coll</n1:D>
                </n1:B>
                <n1:B>
                    <n1:C>X5FL6</n1:C>
                    <n1:D>Coll</n1:D>
                    <n1:E>5</n1:E>
                </n1:B>
             </<n1:A>
     </n0:Partner>
```

I am reading the above XML into an Excel worksheet using the xPath expressions mentioned below

```
     ./n1:A/n1:B/n1:C
     ./n1:A/n1:B/n1:D
     ./n1:A/n1:B/n1:E
```

As element E is missing in the 4th node set (refer to the node block where C = X5FC6), I would like to see an Empty value in the corresponding Excel cell i.e.,

```
             Expected output
             ----------------
              C     D     E
             WZRF8  Coll 1
             X3HV7  Coll 2
             X5E86  Coll 3
             X5FC6  Coll 
             X5FL6  Coll 5
```

Could some one please provide a hint on how to accomplish this output. 
I used the steps of loading an XML document, setting the namespaces, selecting nodes and then identifying the element nodes.

However, the effort resulted in the following output

```
             Actual Output
             --------------
             C      D    E
             WZRF8  Coll 1
             X3HV7  Coll 2
             X5E86  Coll 3
             X5FC6  Coll 5
             X5FL6  Coll
```

Comment: Perhaps you can preprocess the XML. Scan the file and if there are any lines which look like `</n1:B>` which are not proceeded by a line which ends `</n1:E>` then insert the line `<n1:E></n1:E>`. A bit of a kludge but it might work in this specific case.

Comment: Please show your VBA code; it will make it much easier to suggest how to modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could select `B-nodes` first and then loop through them and select `C,D,E` and check for `Nothing` e.g. like this.

> In your VBA-Project add reference to Microsoft XML

```
Option Explicit

Private Const xml As String = "C:\Temp\Sample1.xml"
Private xmlDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
Private partner As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
Private nodesB As MSXML2.IXMLDOMSelection
Private nodeB As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
Private nodeC As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
Private nodeD As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
Private nodeE As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement

Public Sub LoadXmlData()
    Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument

    If Not xmlDoc.Load(xml) Then
        Err.Raise xmlDoc.parseError.ErrorCode, , xmlDoc.parseError.reason
    End If

    Set partner = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("n0:Partner")
    Set nodesB = partner.SelectNodes("./n1:A/n1:B")

    Dim r As Integer
    r = 1
    ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 1) = "C"
    ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 2) = "D"
    ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 3) = "E"

    For Each nodeB In nodesB
        Set nodeC = nodeB.SelectSingleNode("./n1:C")
        Set nodeD = nodeB.SelectSingleNode("./n1:D")
        Set nodeE = nodeB.SelectSingleNode("./n1:E")

        r = r + 1

        If Not nodeC Is Nothing Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 1) = nodeC.Text
        End If

        If Not nodeD Is Nothing Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 2) = nodeD.Text
        End If

        If Not nodeE Is Nothing Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 3) = nodeE.Text
        End If
    Next nodeB
End Sub
```

> Sample data in Sample1.xml

```
<rootElement xmlns:n0="http://www.w3.org/n0/" xmlns:n1="http://www.w3.org/n1/">
    <n0:Partner>
        <n1:Identifier>EMH38</n1:Identifier>
        <n1:A>
            <n1:B>
                <n1:C>WZFR8</n1:C>
                <n1:D>Coll</n1:D>
                <n1:E>1</n1:E>
            </n1:B>
            <n1:B>
                <n1:C>X3HV7</n1:C>
                <n1:D>Coll</n1:D>
                <n1:E>2</n1:E>
            </n1:B>
            <n1:B>
                <n1:C>X5E86</n1:C>
                <n1:D>Coll</n1:D>
                <n1:E>3</n1:E>
            </n1:B>
            <n1:B>
                <n1:C>X5FC6</n1:C>
                <n1:D>Coll</n1:D>
            </n1:B>
            <n1:B>
                <n1:C>X5FL6</n1:C>
                <n1:D>Coll</n1:D>
                <n1:E>5</n1:E>
            </n1:B>
        </n1:A>
    </n0:Partner>
</rootElement>
```

> Output

```
C       D       E
WZFR8   Coll    1
X3HV7   Coll    2
X5E86   Coll    3
X5FC6   Coll    
X5FL6   Coll    5
```